# How to implement these kinds of buttons in React Native?

Tags: react-native

I tried to search for the name of the buttons in the following photo, but I was not able to find them. Can someone tell me how can I use these buttons in React Native along with the name of them?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's `ios`'s  `ActionSheetIOS` component

You could use like this on [example](https://reactnative.dev/docs/actionsheetios.html#example):

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { ActionSheetIOS, Button, StyleSheet, Text, View } from "react-native";

export default App = () => {
  const [result, setResult] = useState("");

  const onPress = () =>
    ActionSheetIOS.showActionSheetWithOptions(
      {
        options: ["Cancel", "Generate number", "Reset"],
        destructiveButtonIndex: 2,
        cancelButtonIndex: 0
      },
      buttonIndex => {
        if (buttonIndex === 0) {
          // cancel action
        } else if (buttonIndex === 1) {
          setResult(Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1);
        } else if (buttonIndex === 2) {
          setResult("");
        }
      }
    );

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text style={styles.result}>{result}</Text>
      <Button onPress={onPress} title="Show Action Sheet" />
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: "center"
  },
  result: {
    fontSize: 64,
    textAlign: "center"
  }
});
```

[DOC](https://reactnative.dev/docs/actionsheetios.html#example)

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer and this is exactly what I was looking for!!